# How to validate range between two number inputs using min and max attributes (AngularJs)

Tags: angularjs, validation, input, numbers

I'm having trouble validating a "from-to" range with AngularJs. The idea is to make a form valid only if the range is from lower to greater number.

```
// Script.js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('RangeController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.data.from = 1;
    $scope.data.to = 10;
});

// HTML
<body ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="RangeController">

        <form name="myForm">
            From: <input type="number" ng-model="data.from" min="0" max="{{ data.to-1 }}" required />
            To: <input type="number" ng-model="data.to" min="{{ data.from+1 }}" required />
        </form>

        myForm.$valid = {{ myForm.$valid }}

    </div>

</body>
```

To reproduce undesired behavior open this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QewK8l8e3Dk5PJTakJj7?p=preview) and type 50 in the "From" input and then type 75 in the "To" field.

With my mind set on "two way data binding" I wonder why didn't "from" input and form became valid when I typed 75 in to the "to" field.

I have searched a bit and found [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2404) discussion but I don't know does it really relates to my problem.

Any taughts?

Comment: Because the "From" gets validated before changing the value of "To". If you change the second value "To", "From" did not realize the modification.

Comment: So you are saying that it validates only when the value of that particular field is changed? I taught since the "max" attribute of "From" get's it's value from "To's" model it will get validated. Is there a way I could trigger validation cycle again somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible to just prevent the user from entering anything but?

Just keep them eyeing one another and when `to` changes set the other or if `from` changes set the `to`

http://plnkr.co/edit/UQCstPAo7mKgROMz8pEB?p=preview

```
app.directive('range',  function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '' +
            '<div>' +
                'From: <input type="number" ng-model="from" />' +
                'To: <input type="number" ng-model="to" />' +
            '</div>',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.$watch('from', function () { $scope.to = $scope.from + 1; });
            $scope.$watch('to', function () { $scope.from = $scope.to - 1; });

            $scope.from = 0;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: If you want to set the form invalid based on this range then that's a different story.